# Connect-Domain does not catch error in the following situation:

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using the connect-domain module (https://github.com/baryshev/connect-domain) to centralize error handling in my Express application.

For the most part it works.  However, for reasons I don't understand, when I throw an error inside of a fs.exists check, it does not catch the error and instead crashes node.

```
app.get( "/anurl/", function( req, res ){
    ...
    fs.exists( filename, function( exists ) {
        if ( !exists ) throw new Error( "bah!" );
        ...
    });
});
```

EDITED:

After quite a bit of testing, I have learned that the above is not the true cause of the problem.

The actual problem is related to using Redis as a session store:

```
app.use( connectDomain() );
app.use( express.session({
    secret: "secretz",
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redis })
}));
```

Using the above, connectDomain no longer works for any errors that are thrown asynchronously.  (This includes calls to fileSystem, timeOuts, database connections, etc.)

If I change the above to the following...

```
app.use( connectDomain() );
app.use( express.session({ secret: "secretz" }));
```

...then everything works perfectly.

So something about RedisStore is breaking Connect-Domain.  Unfortunately I need to use Redis, to persist my sessions.

Any further advice on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I just tryed with this code:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var connectDomain = require('connect-domain');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();
app.use(connectDomain());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    fs.exists('test', function (err) {
        if (!err) throw new Error('bah!');
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Hello World\n');
    });
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.end(err.message);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(1339, '0.0.0.0');
```

Error was successfully catched.

`node.js: 0.10.1`

`connect-domain: 0.5.0`

Comment: Works on Node 0.8 as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  You are correct, this works.  I was mistaken about the cause of the problem, which seems to be related to using Redis as a session store.  Please see my edited question above.

Answer (score 0):

See if it is related with the:

"throw vs throw new" thing

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch2.shtml

Comment: Tried it - Does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228649/unable-to-handle-exception-with-node-js-domains-using-express